# When Executing proc: Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server

Tags: sql-server, oledb

I have an Oracle linked server in my SQL Server database.

I log into SQL Server using local and then Windows authentication.

As the Administrator (which is the account that set up the linked server) I can query directly or embed in a stored proc and then execute the proc without a problem.

As my named user, which has full administrator rights and also has had all SQL Server Groups on the Windows security settings added, I can query my linked server just fine using either synonyms or the OpenQuery syntax.  But if I try to execute one of the stored procedures, it will give me the error messages

```
Message 1:
The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "<server name>" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

Message 2:
Cannot execute the query "<query string>" against OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "<server name>".
```

I have searched online and typically people see this emssage when trying to run an ad hoc query.  My ad hoc query runs just fine.  Still, I applied the solution selected, which was to check the "Allow inprocess" option on the OLEDB Provider.  Doing that did not help.

any ideas?

Comment: I've found that changing the In-Process option often requires a restart of the SQL engine for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Please enable "Allow in Process" option for the provider by opening up Linked Server > Providers and checking on "Allow in Process". For more detail information, please refer to the following link:

Demystifying SQL-Oracle Distributed Query Issues
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bindeshv/archive/2008/05/21/demystifying-sql-oracle-distributed-query-issues.aspx

source: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/902f5edf-e357-4ee7-82e8-ea5760882985/cannot-fetch-a-row-from-ole-db-provider-oraoledboracle-for-linked-server-linkedservername?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: already did that.  See my original post.  But I gave up.  I scrapped the proc and started over. I'm having some success now.